# Add button to jquery ui tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I using jquery tabs, and it's working fine.

I also want to add a button to edit the label of the tab, but jquery don't listening the clic on my button, like a z-index problem. I put a "z-index: 10000;" on the button, but it don't work, i just changing of tab.

My tab :

```
<li><a href="#tab1"><span style="z-index: 100000;" class="button 
   editLibelleCategorie"></span>
   <br>Tabs 1</a>
</li>
```

and my js code :

```
$(document).on('click', '.editLibelleCategorie', function()
{
    alert('ok');
    $("#modalEditCategorie").modal('show');

});
```

Alert is not display when I click on button ...

Thank for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Try the solution as below.

```
$('.editLibelleCategorie').on('click', function()
{
    alert('ok');
    $("#modalEditCategorie").modal('show');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `document` mention Your **class name for the button** in Jquery as follows

```
$('.editLibelleCategorie').on('click', function()
{
    alert('ok');
    $("#modalEditCategorie").modal('show');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
http://jsfiddle.net/6t6yzffa/

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    activate: function (event, ui) {}
});


$('#tabs').on('tabsbeforeactivate', function (event, ui){
    alert('The current tab');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A click on the active tab to rename it:

```
$tabs.on('mouseup', '.ui-tabs-active a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.which === 1)
        Dialog.renameTab($(this))
});
```